# How can I get uploaded file full path in C# 3.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0, filestream, text-files, import

In my ASP.NET MVC website, I have to read a txt file with some names and emails separeted by ';'. After that, I have to save each line of this txt file to database.

Googling around, I've found some snippets, but in all of them I have to use the txt file path.

But, how can I get this path? This file could be anywhere in a user's machine!

Thanks!!

Comment: Is this for an ASP.NET website?

Comment: @Jacob - The user will choose a txt file and when he clicks on a certain button, an Action will be called. In this Action, I have to read all data of this txt file and save them to database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get the full path of an uploaded file.  This would be a privacy violation for the user that uploaded the file.

Instead, you'll need to read the Request.Files that have been uploaded.  For example:

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[0];
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.InputStream))
{
    while ((string line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        string[] addresses = line.Split(';');
        // Do stuff with the addresses
    }
}
```

Comment: Jacob, thanks! I was already going on this direction! :-) It is saving to database, but now I have problems with special characters such as "´", "~' and others.

Comment: I forgot to use the Encoding!! Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a asp.net web page model then `Server.MapPath("~/")` works to get the root of the site so pass the path you need. You might need to call

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
```

For instance a folder where the text files are saved:

```
string directoryOfTexts = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/txtdata/");
```

To just read from it once you have it you can StreamReader it:

```
string directoryOfTexts = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/txtdata/");
string path = directoryOfTexts + "myfile.txt";
string alltextinfile = "";
if (File.Exists(path)) 
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
    {
       //This allows you to do one Read operation.
       alltextinfile = sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

If this is for a desktop application then the Applcation class has all this information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx

```
Application.StartupPath
```

All properties list other appdata folders and stuff but once you have the application path to the executable this gives you context such as `Application.LocalUserAppDataPath`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application_properties.aspx

If the content is small enough you could also just save them in a `HashTable` or a Generic `List<String>` before saving to the database as well.

Comment: Hi Ryan! I don't really need to save the txt file. I just need to read its content and save it to database

Answer (score 0):

```
var hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFile;
```

the form in the HTML should have `enctype="mulitipart/form-data"`