# How to add the path of an uploaded file into a textbox and store it in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a form that registers a new event in events table, In this form i have an upload button that uploads a file and stores it into a folder named as Uploaded_Files.

Everything works properly, but the issue is that:

1) I want the report text box to take the file path while a file is uploaded, so that i could store that path in database.

2) Also how can i upload multiple files and add their paths at the other text boxes, in my example the image1 and image2 text boxes.

This is my model

```
   public class events
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string report { get; set; }
    public string image1 { get; set; }
    public string image2 { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
     //To Retrieve list of events//

     public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var evt = _context.evt;
        if (evt==null)
        {
            return Content("No events registered in database");
        }
        return View(evt);
    }


    //Registering new event//

    public ActionResult Add_New()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(events e)
    {
        _context.evt.Add(e);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Events");
    }


    // Creating Upload Button //

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add_New(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string filepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded_Files"), filename);
                file.SaveAs(filepath);

            }
            ViewBag.Message = "Uploaded Successfully";
            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Not uploaded";
            return View();
        }

    }
```

This is the view:

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Add_New", "Events", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

     {


<div>
    @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" })
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    @ViewBag.Message
</div>


  }


   @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "events"))
  {
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.title)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.title, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.report)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.report, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.image1)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.image1, new { @class = "form-control"})
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.image2)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.image2, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

I know that something has to be merged either in controller or view between the form and upload button, but i can not figure out how to re-write a better logic.

kindly help if you have expertise in this area.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean _take the file path_? You have already specified the path in the POST method (using `Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded_Files")`)

Comment: Where is your `HttpPostedFileBase` and `type="file"` for file inputs? You can get file name using `Server.MapPath` or `Path.GetFileName` depending on your issue. Also your file input seem to exist in different forms with different controller actions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for full path from where file is uploaded. This is limited by browser as it may cause privacy concerns for users

https://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/fileupload-control-doesn-t-give-full-path-help

[How can I get uploaded file full path in C# 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020789/how-can-i-get-uploaded-file-full-path-in-c-sharp-3-0)